# Filling Data to pandas dataframe using loop with text file that have missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I am working on large log files (4 Gig) with 1000 of variables (ABCD,GFHTI,AAAA,BBBB,...)but I am only interested in 50 of these variables (ABCD,GFHTI,..). The structure of the log file is as follow:

```
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451 BLACKBOX ABCD ref 2183 value 24 
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651 BLACKBOX GFHTI  ref 2183 value 25 
20100101_00:01:33.817-92.851 BLACKBOX AAAA ref 2183 value 26   (Not interested in this one)
20100101_00:01:34.017-93.051 BLACKBOX BBBB ref 2183 value 27  (Not interested
 in this one)
```

I am trying to make a pandas data frame out of the this log file which look like this.

```
Time                               ABCD                GFHTI 
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451        24                 NaN 
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651        NaN                25
```

I could do this by using loop and appending to pandas data frame but that is not very efficient.  I can find the value and dates of the value of the interest in the log files but I don't know how to put NaN for the rest of variables for that specific date and time and at the end convert it to a data frame. 
I really appreciate if anyone can help.

Here is part of my code

```
ListOfData={}
fruit={ABCD, GFHTI}
for file in FileList:
   i=i+1
    thefile = open('CleanLog'+str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
    with open(file,'rt') as in_file:
        i=0
        for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):        # Keep track of line numbers.
            if fruit.search(line) != None:# If substring search finds a match,
                i=i+1
                Loc=(fruit.search(line))
                d = [{'Time': line[0:17], Loc.group(0): line[Loc.span()[1]:-1]}]
                for word in Key:
                    if word == Loc.group(0):
                        ListOfData.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse the log file and only return information of interest to the DataFrame constructor

to parse the log lines, I'm using regex here, but the actual parsing function should depend on your log format, also I assume the log file is in the path `log.txt` relative to where this script is run.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def parse_line(line):
    code_pattern = r'(?<=BLACKBOX )\w+'
    value_pattern = r'(?<=value )\d+'
    code = re.findall(code_pattern, line)[0]
    value = re.findall(value_pattern, line)[0]
    ts = line.split()[0]
    return ts, code, value

def parse_filter_logfile(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
       for line in f:
           data = parse_line(line)
           if data[1] in ['ABCD', 'GFHTI']:
               # only yield rows that match the filter
               yield data
```

Then feed that generator to construct a data frame

```
logparser = parse_filter_logfile('log.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(logparser, columns = ['Time', 'Code', 'Value'])
```

finally, pivot the data frame using either of the two statements below

```
df.pivot(index='Time', columns='Code')
df.set_index(['Time', 'Code']).unstack(-1)
```

outputs the following:

```
                             Value      
Code                          ABCD GFHTI
Time                                    
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451    24  None
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651  None    25
```

Hopefully you have enough information to tackle your log file. The tricky part here is dealing with the log line parsing, and you'd have to adapt my example function to get it right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: just one question, I apologize if it is basic, based on this approach my column names are Time, Code and Value. how I can change them to Time,ABCD, GFHTI

Answer (score 1):

When you work with pandas, there is no need to read the file by hand in a loop:

```
data = pd.read_csv('CleanLog.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
```

Use time (#0) and variable name (#2) as index, keep the column with variable values (#6).

```
columns_of_interest = ['ABCD','GFHTI']
data.set_index([0,2])[6].unstack()[columns_of_interest].dropna(how='all')
#2                             ABCD  GFHTI
#0                                        
#20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451  24.0    NaN
#20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651   NaN   25.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The data is really messy. I simplified it for sake of question . for ex.                                                          <20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451 BLACKBOX ABCD ref 2183 value 24> some times the real value is  <20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451 BLACKBOX ABCDGG   32  >  and sometimes <20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451 BLACKBOX ABCD   54 (fjfjdjjsjjajaja)>.